# Proving that $a^{4}+b^{3}+c^{2}\ge a^{3}+b^{3}+c$ for positive real $a,b,c$, $abc\ge 1$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I have been able to simplify the problem. Since $a^{4}\ge a^{3}$ iff $a\ge 1$ (and analogously for $b,c$), $a^{4}+b^{3}+c^{2}\ge a^{3}+b^{3}+c$ holds iff $a+b+c\ge 3$. It is thus sufficient to prove $a+b+c\ge 3$.

I am not sure how to proceeds from there, however.

All insights are really appreciated.

Comment: Your argument seems to be that the inequality hold iff $a \geq 1, b\geq 1$ and $c \geq 1$. This is not the same as $a+b+c \geq 3$.

Comment: Some solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1836393p12315552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe the question should be $a^4+b^3+c^2\ge a^3+b^2+c$.

By AM-GM,

$a^4+a^4+a^4+1\ge 4a^3\Rightarrow a^4\ge \frac{4a^3-1}{3}$

Similarly, $b^3\ge \frac{3b^2-1}{2}$ , $c^2\ge 2c-1$

Hence, $a^4+b^3+c^2\ge \frac{1}{6}(8a^3+9b^2+12c-11)$

So we only need to prove that

$8a^3+9b^2+12c-11\ge 6a^3+6b^2+6c$ , which is equivalent to

$2a^3+3b^2+6c\ge 11$

By AM-GM, $2a^3+3b^2+6c=a^3+a^3+b^2+b^2+b^2+c+c+c+c+c+c\ge 11\sqrt[11]{a^6b^6c^6}\ge 11$

Hence, we are done.